# Kendo Grid - Click event doesn't work in Chrome for an column that has a comobox and an input

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid where a column has an comobobox and an input. The On click event for the input works in IE and Firefox but doesn't work in Chrome.  OnaBai helped create the following jsFiddle and I modified it with the way I have it. http://jsfiddle.net/ehnSq/17/.

Notice if you click on the image in chrome, it just closes the cell. Where as in IE or Firefox you can click the button and get the alert.

Here is my editor for the column.

```
$('<input data-text-field="CustomerName" data-value-field="CustomerId" style="width:175px" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" class="k-combobox"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoComboBox({
            autoBind: false,
            filter: "contains",
            dataSource: customerData,
            placeholder: strings.EmptyDropDownMessage,
            dataTextField: "CustomerName",
            dataValueField: "CustomerId"
        });
    $('<input type="image" class="k-icon-addcustomer" src="../Images/Add2.png" title="' + strings.AddCustomerToolTipText + '" />')
        .appendTo(container);

    $(".k-icon-addcustomer").on("click", function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        alert("Code Needs to Go Here");
    });
```

This will work in IE and Firefox and I am a loss why the click event is not fired in chrome.

Comment: I noticed that if you remove the combobox out, the click event works.

Comment: I figured out the issue, the issue is in chrome, the blur event on the combobox masked the click event. So by binding a blur event to the combobox and stopping the propagation of the event fixed the issue.